# Asynchronous Object Construction in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, asynchronous

I'm currently working on an app with a reasonably complex Core Data model.  The data model currently has 10 tables in it, with a bunch of relationships set between them.  The data for the model is obtained piecemeal from a remote server. In order to minimize the amount of traffic to/from the server, the server API passes object ID's first, giving me a chance to discover if I already have stored the objects.  If not, then I can ask the server for the full objects and store them.  However, those objects can have references to other objects, for which I will need to check follow the same process: check if I have the object(s) and, if not, grab the objects from the server. The Core Data model includes fields for the server IDs which I use to validate and construct Core Data's object graph.

This creates a situation where objects will have been instantiated in Core Data, but won't have been completely constructed as they may be waiting for referenced objects to be returned by the server (which may, in turn, need to wait for their own reference objects).

So my first attempt to deal with this was to create a semaphore that would not allow the object context to be saved (I only save the context in one place) until all objects are downloaded and the object graph is constructed.  The problem I ran into was that the context was being saved anyway, without me asking.  This results in a ton of changes propagating through `NSFetchedResultsController` as objects are downloaded from the server and the object graph is being constructed.  Moreover, the propagated objects may not be complete.

Has any dealt with anything like this?  I think this could all work if I could explicitly control when Core Data saves, but that does not appear to be possible.  Or am I missing something?

#### UPDATE

I *was* missing something.  I was under the impression that `NSFetchedResultsController` received updates when the Context is saved.  This is not true.  It receives updates whenever `processPendingChanges` is called in the context, which occurs at the end of an event cycle.  In the past, I've always used two contexts to keep updates separate from the UI, but this project had a deadline and existing code that kept me from refactoring. Given this new information, I think the separate context will fix my problem.

Comment: Are you using parent-child contexts? If so, if you propagate your changes to a common parent, they may be persisted in a later save. You should create a dedicated child context, which will aggregate the changes, and only save it when you are ready with your objects. It will not get saved by the system.

Comment: That's just the problem.  It *is* getting saved somewhere by something other than me.  I did a search on all my code to make sure I wasn't calling `save:` on the context.  I only call it in one place. It wasn't being called, but the context was being saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an extremely expensive way to sync with a server.  Is there a reason your server can't respond to "changed since X" calls and give you everything?  In your current design you are spending more time opening and closing sockets than you are receiving data.

Be that as it may, you want to do all of this processing in a secondary context that is connected directly to the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.  When it saves you want to capture the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and then have your UI context consume that notification.  That will update your UI when your server sync is complete.

This will keep your syncing 100% isolated from the UI and allow the UI to save or do whatever else it needs to do while you are working with the server.  I would not use a parent/child design here.  There is no reason to.

Comment: It's not as expensive as they *were* doing it, which was to pass all the objects all the time. Grabbing "new objects since" is one of the changes I'm pushing for.  Anyway, creating a separate Context was actually next on the Task list, I just misunderstood how changes were propagated to `NSFetchedResultsController` and wanted to fix this (or clarify my understanding) before I moved on to creating a separate context.  Looks like moving forward is actually the fix.

Comment: Also, my goal isn't to sync all the server data with the client (which would be massive), but instead to grab only the relevant info.  This is why I take objects references and only grab those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You access a core data database via the NSManagedObjectContext class.

Each context object must belong to a single thread, and any NSManagedObjects that context creates belong to the same thread.

Do not read or write any managed object from a thread other than the one that created it. If you do, you'll end up with unpredictable and impossible to debug data corruption problems.

However, you can have multiple NSManagedObjectContext instances for a single core data database, each one on a different thread, and you can merge any changes made to the context in one thread over to a context on another thread.

So, basically, you have a "main" NSManagedObjectContext which is used on the main thread, and used for almost all your operations. And then when you need to do something on another thread you create a "child" context for that thread, make all your changes, then merge those changes back to the main context on the main thread.

You can find specific details how to implement this from Apple's official documentation. Start reading here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

Comment: I'm aware of how to use multiple contexts.  That, in fact, is my next step in the project.  It was part of the original design, but got delayed because of a deadline (moved into the next project phase). This might be the problem though.  I've always used multiple contexts in the past...  this is the first time I used a single context for expediency.

Comment: @AaronHayman so you have one context and you're talking to it on two threads? You can't do that. Seriously. It doesn't matter if you put safeguards in to make sure nothing talks to it simultaneously on different threads, the documentation clearly says never to call any method on any context or managed object or fetched results controller from a thread other than the one that created the context.

Comment: No. I've got one context, one thread.  Setting up another private context to perform the syncing operations on is my next task (something I'm working on now).